# Misanthropic Neighbors

Tags: probability

This week's [538 riddler](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-solve-the-puzzle-of-your-misanthropic-neighbors/) is:

> The misanthropes are coming. Suppose there is a row of some number, `N`, of houses in a new, initially empty development. Misanthropes are moving into the development one at a time and selecting a house at random from those that have nobody in them *and* nobody living next door. They keep on coming until no acceptable houses remain. At most, one out of two houses will be occupied; at least one out of three houses will be. But what’s the *expected fraction* of occupied houses as the development gets larger, that is, as `N` goes to infinity?

If we define $E_N$ to be the expected number of occupied houses given $N$ houses in a row, then I could work out the recurrence as: $$E_N = 1 + \frac2N\sum_{i=1}^{N-2}E_i$$ just based on the open spaces left after we fix the first misanthrope moving in. However, I have no idea where to go from here - either in finding a closed form for $E_N$ that I can take the limit of or coming up with a different way of thinking about this problem. What's the next step?

Comment: Nice solution, I agree with your equation, which is the same as $nE_n = n + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}E_i$.  One next step might be $$(n+1)E_{n+1}=(n+1)+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E_i = (n+1) + 2E_{n-1} + (nE_n-n) = 1 + 2E_{n-1} + nE_n$$

Comment: A class of particular solutions to the equation $(n+1)E_{n+1} = 1 + 2E_{n-1} + nE_n$ have the form $an+b$ for $3a=1+b$.

Comment: @Michael Not sure what you mean by the form?

Comment: I mean that for all real numbers $a$, we observe that $E_n^{particular}=an+b$ solves the inhomogeneous linear recurrence relation $(n+1)E_{n+1} = 1 + 2E_{n-1}+nE_n$  (provided that $b=3a-1$).  To completely solve $E_n$ in closed form, you just need one more (non-affine) solution $x_n$ to the _homogeneous_ equation $(n+1)x_{n+1} = 2x_{n-1} + nx_n$.  Then $E_n=E_n^{particular} + cx_n$ is your answer, for appropriately chosen $a,c$ that match initial conditions $E_1=1,E_2=1$. That is: $$E_n = an + (3a-1) + cx_n$$ where $a,c$ satisfy  $1=a + (3a-1) + cx_1$ and $1 = 2a+(3a-1)+cx_2$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{E_n}{n} = \frac{1-e^{-2}}{2}$. See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758238/59379) to a related question.

Answer (score 3):

Michael pointed out that an equivalent recurrence relation is 
$$ (n+1)E_{n+1} = n E_n + 2E_{n-1} + 1.$$
We can solve this with generating functions. Let 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n x^n.$$ 
Then we can construct a few useful quantities from this. First, note that
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n E_n x^{n-1}.$$ 
Multiplying this by $x$ gives the useful relation
$$ x \frac{df}{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n E_n x^n.$$
Additionally, note that
$$ \frac{df}{dx} = E_1 + 2 E_2 x + 3E_3 x^2 + \cdots = E_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1) E_{n+1} x^n.$$
Multiplying $f(x)$ by $x$ gives us
$$x f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n x^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{n-1} x^n,$$
where we shifted the index in the last step.
Finally, from Taylor expanding about $x=0$, we have that
$$ \frac{x}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n.$$
Using this, we can write
$$ \frac{df}{dx} - E_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)E_{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( nE_n + 2E_{n-1} + 1\right) = x \frac{df}{dx} + 2x f + \frac{x}{1-x}.$$
This gives us a first order differential equation for $f$. If there's only one house, then it clearly gets occupied, so $E_1 = 1$. Rearranging yields
$$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{2x}{1-x} f + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$
This differential equation can be solved exactly to give
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x} \sinh(x)}{(1-x)^2},$$
where we use the fact that $f(0) = E_0 = 0$ as our initial condition (since no houses can be occupied if there are no houses in the first place). Expanding this function in a Taylor series about $x=0$ gives the coefficients $E_n$ since
$$ E_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left.\frac{d^n f}{dx^n}\right|_{x=0}.$$
After playing with the series expansion a bit, you can show that
$$ E_n = \frac{n+1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k \frac{(n-k+1)}{k!},$$
which is a nice closed form solution for $E_n$. From here, you can work out $\lim_{n\to \infty} E_n/n$ which should give you the expected fraction of occupied houses.

Answer (score 1):

Ak = Permutations in which house K is occupied
 = Bk Permutations in which house K - 1 is empty (but not K-2) 
   + Ck Permutations in which house K - 1 and K -2 are empty

So eK = Expected occupancy for House K = Ak / ( Ak+ Bk + Ck)
So eN = Sum of eK over N  / N

Model needs adjustment for corner cases for K = 1, 2 and N (Ck is 0)

But even without the adjustment, as N-> Infinity, Expected fraction -> 43% 
- as shown in the image

[Misanthrope solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6osx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit naive, but here's my approach:

Each time a new misanthrope moves in, there are either 2 or 3 fewer houses available for the next misanthrope.

Case #1 - 3 fewer houses: If a misanthrope moves into a house, the next misanthrope can't move into that house or either neighboring house.

Case #2 - 2 fewer houses: If a misanthrope moves into a house that is 2 doors down from an occupied house, the common neighbor between them was already removed from the potential selection pool, so there are now 2 fewer houses to choose from.

Because housing selection is random, both cases occur with equal probability.  So, on average when a new misanthrope moves in, there are 2.5 fewer houses to choose for the next misanthrope.

If there are N houses, where N is large (so that we can ignore the houses on the ends), then we expect x number of misanthropes to be able to move in, where 2.5x = N.  You can think of this as the effective number of houses each misanthrope occupies.  The expectation value then is just x/N which is (1/2.5) or 2/5 or 0.4.

Thus, the expected fraction of occupied houses is 0.4 as N goes to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

If there are n houses. Then 1 accepted event is 1 house out of n or 2 out of n all the way to n/2 out of n

So fraction of occupied houses is sum of 1,2,...n/2   Divided by nsqaured

Take a limit if n is infinity will be 25%

Comment: The fraction of occupied houses must be at least $1/3$, since every three consecutive houses has at least one being occupied.