# Limit of recursive sequence $n^2q_n=1+(n-1)^2q_{n-1}+2(n-2)q_{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

When looking at [this riddle](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-solve-the-puzzle-of-your-misanthropic-neighbors/), I came across the following sequence for the frequency of sampled integers between 1 and $n$ in a without replacement/without neighbour sampling:
$$q_1=1,\quad q_2=1/2,\quad q_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}q_{n-1}+\frac{2(n-2)}{n^2}q_{n-2}\quad (n>2)$$
and I wonder if there is a generic mathematical approach to computing an analytic solution for $$\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n$$Assessing the numerical limit with an R code like

```
q=rep(1,1e7)
for (n in 3:1e7) q[n]=(1+2*q[n-2]+(n-1)*q[n-1])/n
q[1e7]/1e7
```

led me to $0.432332...$ And a probabilistic reasoning indicates that $(n>1)$ $$\frac{1}{3}\le q_n\le \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Do you have any conjectures? Does computing the first 10,000 numbers numerically give an idea? – Where did you "come across" that sequence? Some context might be helpful.

Comment: Some MATLAB/GNU Octave code to get you started:
N = 100; q_2 = 1.; q_1 = 0.5; fprintf("q_1 = %f\n", q_2); fprintf("q_2 = %f\n", q_1); for n=3:N; q_0 = 1./(n\*n) + (n-1)\*(n-1)/(n\*n)\*q_1 + 2\*(n-2)/(n\*n)\*q_2; fprintf("q_%d = %f\n", n, q_0); q_2 = q_1; q_1 = q_0; end;

Comment: @MartinR: In the OP's defense let me say that I have just implemented the code for this sequence in Mathematica 7 and `q[30]` is already slow to compute. I am afraid that for `10000` one would require a whole cluster. It seems, though, that the sequence is *veeery* slowly decreasing to some value between `0.4` and `0.5` - even though it is not reasonable to expect to draw a conclusion by the first 30 terms.

Comment: Using the code above, $q_{10000}\approx 0.432362058089209$ can be computed in < 1 second on a modern machine

Comment: By simple algebra, if there is a limit it has to be $\frac{1}{3}$. But it converges extremely slowly.

Comment: @almagest: I'm not sure that is true

Comment: @par: The space and time required for the computation of a doubly-recursive expression grow exponentially (each level of the computation creates two new subtrees in the call tree of the evaluation - unless one uses some form of memoization).

Comment: @Did Solve $k=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{k(n-1)^2}{n^2}+\frac{2k(n-2)}{n^2}$.

Comment: @AlexM. The code above is $O(1)$ space, $O(n)$ time. The lack of memoization might be a by-product of a Mathematica implementation.

Comment: @almagest is correct, if there is a converging solution then $q_n \sim q_{n-1} \sim q_{n-2}$ so to solve that equation^ could would give the value of $q_n$ if it converges to anything. In this case $q_n = \frac{1}{3}$ is the only valid solution, so if it does converge to something, it'll be that.

Comment: @almagest Yes, this is the obvious step but it does not prove  convergence to zero since, using $r_n=q_n-\frac13$, one gets $$r_n=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}r_{n-1}+\frac{2(n-2)}{n^2}r_{n-2},$$ which is solved by some sequences $(r_n)$ decreasing to some nonzero limit. Hint: $$\prod_n\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}+\frac{2(n-2)}{n^2}\right)=\prod_n\left(1-{}{}{}{}\frac{3}{n^2}\right)>0.$$

Comment: @Xi'an: The code that you give does not implement the formula that you give. Which of the two is the one you mean? Also, your code gives no `q[1]`, so it should end with an error. Are you sure that you have really run it?

Comment: @Xi'an: It is still not correct.

Comment: @Xi'an: This is what you *think* it does, not what it *really* does. Why is it `(n-1)` instead of `(n-1)^2`?

Comment: @AlexM.: If you set $s_n=nq_n$, then the sequence becomes$$ns_n=1+(n-1)s_{n-1}+2s_{n-2}$$with $s_1=s_2=1$.

Comment: @par: $O(1)$ space means constant space. Clearly not the case here. Try it with a huge value for $n$ and you'll get a stack overflow (the recursion being too deep).

Comment: @AlexM. As far as I can see, there's no recursion in par's code.

Comment: @almagest Actually my first comment *proves* that if there is a limit $\ell$ then $$\ell\geqslant\frac13+\frac16\prod_{n=3}^\infty\left(1-\frac3{n^2}\right)>0.378.$$

Comment: @par: I apologize, I looked at the OP's code, not at yours.

Comment: @Did I agree that we need to prove that the sequence tends to a limit. But you cannot blithely say that $r_n=\prod(1-\frac{3}{n^2})$. That is obviously false. You are simultaneously assuming that $n$ is so large that $r_{n-1}=r_{n-2}$ and that $r_n$ is significantly larger than $r_{n-1}$.

Comment: @almagest your equation makes sense only in the limit when $n\to \infty$, where it is the trivial $k=k$.

Comment: @Macavity I agree it is heuristic rather than a proof. So far I have not even seen a proof that the sequence converges.

Comment: @almagest Sorry but I strongly suggest that you read carefully what I really wrote instead of inventing (obviously false) statements. Where do you see that I would have written that $r_n=\prod\left(1-\frac3{n^2}\right)$ (a statement not even notationally correct, by the way)?

Comment: @almagest Since the math argument does not seem to percolate, I suggest that we wait for numerical evidence to accumulate, showing that the limit $\frac13$ is wrong and that the lower bound in my comment is correct -- and then maybe you will revise your comment.

Comment: @Xi'an ?? I know.

Comment: @almagest Convergence doesn't seem hard to show, it is clearly bounded and decreasing, which can be rigorously proved by induction. Findi the limit however is another matter altogether.

Comment: @AlexM.: when running the alternative code `for (n in 3:1e9){ c=(1+2*a+(n-1)*b)/n;a=b;b=c}` started with `a=b=1`, the storage gets to O(n).

Comment: $q_n$ should converge to $\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2} \approx 0.4323323583816936$.

Comment: @achillehui: nice. can you show us the argument?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $a_n = (n+1)q_{n+1}$. We have $a_0 = a_1 = 1$ and

$$(n+1)a_n = 1 + na_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}\quad\text{ for }\quad n > 1\tag{*1}$$

Let $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, multiply $(*1)$ by $z^n$ and start to sum from $n = 2$, we get

$$\begin{align}
& \left(z\frac{d}{dz} + 1 \right)(f(z) - 1 - z) = \frac{z^2}{1-z} + \left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)(z(f(z)-1)) + 2z^2f(z)\\
\iff &
zf' + f - 1 -2z = \frac{z^2}{1-z} + z^2 f' + zf - z + 2z^2 f\\
\iff &
z(1-z)f' + (1-z-2z^2)f = \frac{1}{1-z}
\end{align}
$$
Solving the ODE give us

$$f(z) = \frac{1-e^{-2z}}{2z(1-z)^2} = \frac{A}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{B}{(1-z)} + g(z)\tag{*2}$$
where 
$\displaystyle\;\begin{cases}
A &= \frac{1-e^{-2}}{2}\\
B &= \frac{1-3e^{-2}}{2}\\
\end{cases}\;
$
and $g(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_n z^n$ 
is some function analytic over all $\mathbb{C}$.

Expanding $(*2)$ as a power series and compare coefficients of $z^n$ on both sides, we get

$$(n+1)q_{n+1} = a_n = (n+1)A + B + g_n$$

Since $g(z)$ is entire, its coefficients of taylor expansion $g_n$ is bounded.
As a result,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} q_{n+1} 
&= A + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{B + g_n}{n+1} = A = \frac{1 - e^{-2}}{2}\\
&\approx 0.432332358381693654053000252513757798296184227045212059265
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If only I could upvote twice.

Comment: Very impressive!!!

Comment: @achillehui: Concise and instructive presentation. Very nice!

Comment: @Did wow, thanks for the big bonus.