# Recurrence relation to solve

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, oeis

I have one problem that can be transformed into recurrence relation shown below, I guess $a_{n} = O(n)$. But I cannot solve the analytic form of $a_{n}$, can anyone help me on this?
$$(n-2)a_{n+1}-(n-3)a_{n}=2a_{n-1}, n>=3$$
$$a_{2}=1, a_{3}=1$$
Follow this relation
$$a_{4}=2, a_{5}=2, a_{6}=8/3, a_{7}=3$$

Comment: Generating functions. Multiply through by $z^n$ and sum over $n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this is recurrence from problem of Misanthropic Neighbors, which can be solved by generating functions.

[Misanthropic Neighbors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757228/misanthropic-neighbors)

[Limit of recursive sequence $n^2q_n=1+(n-1)^2q_{n-1}+2(n-2)q_{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758065/limit-of-recursive-sequence-n2q-n-1n-12q-n-12n-2q-n-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)